# How to add a datepicker field in Shipping address step at Customized checkout?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, checkout-page, datepicker, shipping-step

In the checkout page, we have two of the options. First one is School and the second one is Private person. Customer can order via school option and as well as the private person. In both the option, we have shipping address step and payment step.

[image]

Now, we want to add a datepicker field in shipping address step at school option. How to do it?

Could anyone please give me your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The checkout is difficult to customise

What you need is a checkout custom field extension

Something like this

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-checkout-custom-field-extension.html

Comment: My requirement is to create a custom field without using any third party plugin